# Prepare .npy data using Numpy for input for CNN

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am new to python. I have .npy file for input for my CNN model. So many examples out there is **using keras and I'm not allowed to use that**. So, I want to read 1 array on my .npy file. For example, my file consist of pixels of images :

```
[ [ 120, 120],
  [ 120, 120],
  .................,
  [ 120, 120] ]
```

There are `20` lines. If i use `input = np.load(myfile.npy)` then `input.shape()` the result is of course `(20, 2)`. 
I can't use that for my model. Because the input should be `(120,120)`.

So how can I read 1 array in that file? Or maybe you can tell me the best way to use own image for CNN. Thank you, Sorry for bad English :)

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1wmI3wO2ePDmZW5loFf2DsgDD9Og0lhyU the image file and it's label

Comment: can you add the file ?

Comment: @seralouk I added it :)

Comment: Okay. What exactly is your problem. In this file you have stores the image data. Is the `(20,2)` dimensions correct?

Comment: @seralouk yes the file is stores numpy array of image. The image size is 120 x 120. If i save it in npy file it becomes 1 array that consist many array of images. (20, 2) is just an example, the file dimension i think (53, 2) i forgot i'm sorry. But (20,2) it means there are 20 rows and 2 coloums right?  Each row is 1 image. My problem is i want to read 1 image not all. I dont know how to explain it well i'm sorry

Comment: @seralouk i mean i want to read each image, sorry not 1 but each image. So i didn' twant to read the dimension of the file but each dimension inside the file.  I think i need to loop it right? But i dont know how :( i hope u understand :(

Comment: I think that the images are not correctly stored in the .npy file.  The file has shape (57,3) and you said that each row is an image. But this is not the case, each row is simply an array like (120,120). Only 2 values

Comment: @seralouk okaay so how can i load each of the array?

Comment: You cannot. I believe that the .npy file is not correctly created. It should contain 2D rows (images) not vectors like your case. How did you generated this npy file ?

Comment: @seralouk this is how I generate imag = Image.open(file)
        
        width, height = imag.size
        
        channels = 1
        
        pixel_values = list(imag.getdata())
        
        pixel_value = np.array(pixel_values).reshape(channels, width, height)
        
        data.append(pixel_value.shape), then use np.save to save the file. if it wrong, then how to correctly generate the file ?

Comment: @seralouk but can i really use .npy file for cnn input?

Comment: Yes it is wrong !!!!! You use: `data.append(pixel_value.shape)` . So you save the DIMENSIONS NOT the images. USE THIS to save: `data.append(pixel_value)` and then np.save(data)

Comment: see my answer. it should solve your problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Your Problem

It seems that you have saved the data in the wrong way.
After your last comment, I found the initial problem.

Currently, you use this `data.append(pixel_value.shape)` and then you save this as `.npy`.
What you are actually doing here, **is saving the dimensions of the data and not the data itself.**

So, when I load the `.npy` file from the link that you posted, I have this:

> ```
> array([[  1, 120, 120],
>        [  1, 120, 120],
>        [  1, 120, 120],
>        [  1, 120, 120],
> ```

You are saving the dimensions of the `pixel_value`.

---

### How to solve this

So, use this to date the actual data: `data.append(pixel_value)`.

Then I should be trivial how to load the file:

```
data_all = np.load('file.npy')

# get the first image
img1 = data_all[0]
```

Comment: perfect. please consider upvoting my answer if it helps